# Проверка инициализации ArrayList

Tags: java, android, arraylist, инициализация

Подскажите пожалуйста. Имеется массив ArrayList. Его я объявляю в классе переменных:

```
private ArrayList<Part> parts;
```

Как написать проверку инициализирован ли он или нет? и если нет, то инициализировать. Следующий код неверный:

```
public ArrayList<Part> initArrayList(Part part){
    if (parts.isEmpty()) {
        parts = new ArrayList<>();
        parts.add(part);
        }
    else parts.add(part);

    return parts;
```

Comment: Пустой (isEmpty) это уже инициализированный. Надо проверять равенством с null как в ответе ниже. new ArrayList() каждый раз создаёт аррай, который будет isEmpty (если в него ничего не поместить конечно)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Как написать проверку инициализирован ли он или нет? и если нет, то инициализировать.

Например, так:

```
public ArrayList<Part> initArrayList(ArrayList<Part> parts) {
    if (parts == null) {
        return new ArrayList<>();
    }
    return parts;
}
```

**UPD**.

Ввиду уровня заданного вопроса, специально не хотел путать автора [тернарным оператором](http://sernam.ru/book_java.php?id=16), но если Вы про него знаете, то метод `initArrayList(...)` можно реализовать несколько короче:

```
public static ArrayList<Part> initArrayList(ArrayList<Part> parts) {
    return parts == null ? new ArrayList<>() : parts;
}
```

А вообще, это т.н. *syntactic sugar*, не более того.

Comment: return parts == null ? new ArrayList() : parts; да и лишний переброс ссыли в метод чтоб сделать провекру, нуууууу... уж жирновато нет? 
Чем это отличается от if (parts != null) parts.add(new Part); в теории, хоть и маловероятно, есть возможность словить палку причем ударить может обеими сторонами, ну и ладно, плюсуют, и то хорошо))

Comment: @ShwarzAndrei, 1. Я специально не стал путать человека, который задает подобного уровня вопросы, тернарным оператором. 2. У автора код был оформлен в виде метода – так и оставил.

Comment: @m.vokhm, Поясните, пожалуйста, по поводу «если `parts` не инициализирован, он так и останется `null` после выполнения такого кода».

Comment: @post_zeew, я невнимательно посмотрел, не заметил, что parts - это аргумент метода, показалось, что речь идет о поле объекта. Снимаю свое замечание.

Answer (score 3):

```
// Запрос списка через добавление элемента с ленивой инициализацией списка
public ArrayList<Part> initArrayList(Part part){
    if (parts == null) parts = new ArrayList<>();
    parts.add(part);
    return parts;
}

    // Работать будет, но правильнее разнести две различные функции по разным методам

// Запрос списка с ленивой инициализацией
public List<Part> getParts() {
    if (parts == null) parts = new ArrayList<>();
    return parts;
}
// Добавление элемента в список
public void addPart(Part part) {
    getParts().add(part);
}
```

Comment: Комментируйте код в ответах - обосновывайте ваше решение

Comment: Добавил комментарии в код и пояснение, почему так делать не совсем правильно.

Answer (score 2):

Вообще по идее ваше поле **parts** проинициализировано с самого начала, т.к. все поля объекта в java инициалищируются их значением по-умолчанию. Вот только так как ArrayList - объект, то дефолтное значение будет **null**. А если вы хотите, чтоб у вас был именно рабочий экземпляр ArrayList, то можно поступить как в предыдущем ответе, либо вообще задать значение поля при объявлении:

```
private ArrayList<Part> parts = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: Иногда бывает нужно различать, работали мы уже с ним или нет, и тога есть смысл держать там null, как признак того, что еще не обращались. А при обращении к нему делать так: `if (parts == null) parts = new ArrayList(); return parts;`

Comment: Это понятно, просто в данном случае автор поста по всей видимости пытается забежать вперед, толком не разобравшись, что же из себя представляет ArrayList, да и объект в целом, поэтому я попробовал объяснить